# Cormen quick sort modify partition function

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, quicksort

I am learning quick sort from Introduction to Algorithms.I got stuck on question [7.1-2.](http://clrs.skanev.com/07/01/02.html) of Chapter 7 Quicksort-

### "What value of q does PARTITION return when all elements in the array A[p…r] have the same value? Modify PARTITION so that q=⌊(p+r)/2⌋ when > all elements in the array A[p…r] have the same value."

The first part is easy and the answer is definitely r.But I can't even figure out what the second part is asking.I mean what is the reason for setting the pivot to (p+r)/2.Further I can't understand the solutions I found on searching on Google.

Please help me in understanding what is the advantage of this modification in case all elements are equal and if possible please provide the algorithm to do so.

Comment: Links can break, consider quoting the relevant parts.

Comment: The answer to your question is literally the next paragraph in the next section.

Answer (score 0):

By setting the pivot to the middle of p and r, we divide the array of size n into two sub-problems of equal size n/2. If you draw the recursion tree for the following recurrence, you would see its height as O(lgn)

T(n) = 2T(n/2)+O(n)

Imagine if the position of the pivot returned from the partition is always the last element in the array. Then the recurrence for the run time would be

T(n) = T(n-1)+O(n)

Do you see now why is it inefficient if the recursion tree is like a linked list? Try drawing the tree and adding the costs at each node in both the cases.

Also modifying the partition method to return (p+r)/2 is easy.

Hint: One easy way is split <= in the if condition of the partition.